# Passing array from one class to another using delegation - Best design pattern?

Tags: objective-c, ios, design-patterns, singleton

**The Problem**

I have a class which calculates the path a user took using CoreLocation and and array of arrays containing the coordinates of each point (taken when the users location changes). This class method is being called by my View Controller, but I want to set it's delegate to another class which will store the result in Core Data or upload it to a database. I can return the array to the View Controller by using:

```
PathFinder.delegate = self
```

Then make my View Controller implement my delegate protocol, but this isn't what I want.

**What I've Considered**

I've thought about making the class which uploads the data to the database/stores it in Core Data a singleton class so that I can easily access it from my View Controller. E.g.

```
PathFinder.delegate = <MY SINGLETON CLASS>
```

**Conclusion**

What would be the best way to do this? Would it be bad practice to put the code to upload the array to my server in the PathFinder class? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something like this - a singleton class that manages a Core Data repository for images (some in the repository, some on the file system but a URL in the entity).

Why not have a singleton class that all objects that need the services import? That way, you tell some object to do something, when that works is done they tell the repository to save it. You can use a delegate protocol to know if it succeeded or not, but just decouple the saving of it from driving the process and knowing the outcome.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of this but didn't know if it was an acceptable practice.

Comment: In the end, good practice proves itself. As time goes on, is it costing you lots of time changing? Does it cause inconsistency? Or, is it making your life easier as you add functionality? I answered this but 10 other people could have 10 other suggestions. In the end, sit back with a pencil and paper, and think, is this a good way to extract a complex function so a few classes can use it easily, and perhaps in the future more can use it easily later? I had just this with my image singleton - I ended up needing other classes to use it, and it just took a few lines of code to add the support.